# How could I get the CGPoint of the TapGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have got the source code:

```
fileprivate struct ImageWrapper: View {

    var body: some View {
        let fitToFill = TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                //How could I get the CGPoint here?
            }

         return Image(uiImage: image)
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .gesture(fitToFill)        
        }        
}
```

I want to get the click point when it's the end of TapGesture. But I could not find the way in the document. How could I do with it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```swift
fileprivate struct ImageWrapper: View {
    let image: UIImage

    @State var lastLocation: CGPoint = .zero
    var body: some View {
        let fitToFill = TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                // << use self.lastLocation here as needed
            }.simultaneously(with: 
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged { value in
                // location in image own coordinates, if needed in screen,
                // then change above coordinateSpace to .global
                self.lastLocation = value.location 
            })

         return Image(uiImage: image)
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .gesture(fitToFill)
        }
}
```